# JAVA for windows mobile 5.0

Tags: java, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm having this issue with an app I have written for a Scanner running windows mobile 5.0. I have no idea what it means, can anyone with some Java Cre-Me, windows mobile experience lend some assistance please??

Error given on execution:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SymbolJavaApi in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryInternal() 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary()
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0()
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary()
    at 
    at com.vmt.plugins.symbol.barcodescanner.services.ScannerImplementation.read()
    at com.vmt.plugins.symbol.barcodescanner.ScannerPlugin.invoke()
    at ScannerTest.startScanning()
    at ScannerTest.createwindow()
    at ScannerTest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

For `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, the JDK states:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate
>   native-language definition of a method declared native.

That means that there is a method inside `ScannerImplementation.read()` that is a native call definition that it can't in the `java.library.path` or any system defined libraries.

What this means is that the DLL that is needed for your `ScannerImplementation` isn't registered in the Java LIB path and thus the JVM can't do a native call.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Java class loader tries to access the Symbol API but can not find the required libraries in the given library path.

On a desktop system I'd say you need:

1. Either extend the class path accordingly or
2. Copy missing external DLLs to the path where your application resides

I'm sure that Symbol/Motorola has some examples where you can see how to do that - maybe you need to install the classes to the device first using a CAB file.

I'm coming from a .NET background and for that, there's a Symbol API CAB file which installs required DLLs to the device.